# Wpf ListView Binding items to Enum

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I am doign some stuff in WPF, and I have this in Xaml:

```
<ListView Name="lview" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <ListViewItem>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="C:\blue.png" />
                        <TextBlock>Blue</TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="C:\green.png" />
                        <TextBlock>Green</TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

And I would like to achieve, that every ListViewItem is binded with the Enum value, for example with Enums.COLORS.Blue, Enums.COLORS.Green and so on...

What is the best way to achieve this, preferably with not-breaking MVVM?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CollectionViewSource` with `ObjectDataProvider` and bind the `ItemsSource` of your `ListView` to the `CollectionViewSource`. But, by binding to an enum value, I'm not sure how you will assign the image source because you will not have multiple properties like a class, unless you use a converter to get the correct image file Uri or BitmapSource.

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="ColoursSource"  x:Shared="False"> 
    <CollectionViewSource.Source>
      <ObjectDataProvider 
        MethodName="GetValues" 
        ObjectType="{x:Type system:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
          <x:Type TypeName="entities:Colours" />
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
      </ObjectDataProvider>
    </CollectionViewSource.Source>
  </CollectionViewSource>
```

...

```
<ListView Name="lview" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ColoursSource}}">
</ListView>
```